# Замок Иф через В

Tags: орфография

Из книги "Жизнь — сапожок непарный" Тамары Петкевич:

> Это карта из замка И**в**! Клад зарыт именно тут!..

Что это — ошибка, опечатка?

Answer (score 1):

Ну это только автор может наверняка сказать, что сие есть.

Но в принципе я не буду удивлен, если это некое чрезмерное стремление передать французскую фонетику. Конечный F в каких-то случаях на русский слух можно воспринять как звонкий звук. Впрочем, с французским у меня не здорово, может это только мне так кажется.

Comment: Спасибо! У меня тоже с французским не так хорошо, то есть читать-произносить в целом знаю как, но таких тонкостей могу не знать. Если этот момент фонетический действительно имеет место, то тогда это очень похоже на английское 'of', в котором всегда звучит звонкое В.

Comment: Если это тот самый замок, то правила франко-русской практической транскрипции требуют однозначности в написании (здесь -ф): https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D1%83%D0%B7%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: @Alex_ander Правила-то требует, кто б сомневался. Но мы ищем мотив, а не основания.

Comment: Вероятный "мотив" автора - звуковая идентичность элементов русских словосочетаний "замок Иф" и "Ив Монтан" :)

Comment: Тогда это не мотив, а недоразумение.